# why do i not get the correct value for sum?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumArray(int* p);

int main(){

    int array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, sum;
    int* p = array;
    sum = printf("The sum of the array is: %d", sumArray(p));
    return 0;
}

int sumArray(int* p){

    int sum = 0;
    while(*p){
        sum += *p;
        p++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

when i run this code i get a 6-digit value for sum, which looks more like an address. so what exactly am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Because your array does not include the sentinel value of zero.

Comment: Your code invokes UB by reading past the end of an array

Comment: A better approach: declare a constant with the number of elements in the array, pass that count to your sumArray method, and use a `for` loop.

Comment: Why is the loop condition `while(*p)`? This is the same as `while(*p != 0)`. Why would _any_ random array contain zero?

Comment: @ForceBru: Strings in c (character arrays) contain that, by definition.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, sure - that's why I said "_any_ random array". Also, OP is dealing with integers here. Indeed, the idea to check array length with `while (*p)` seems to stem from string processing...

Comment: For a numerical array, which can supposedly contain any value in `int` range, sentinel value cannot be used.

Comment: for obtaining the length of the array, suggest;  `int length = sizeof( array) / sizeof( array[0] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while(*p)` is a pretty idiomatic way of processing *character strings* in C because they have the useful property of being null-terminated. Once the null terminator (character with numeric value of 0) is reached, `*p` is 0 and the loop ends.

Your array does not have this property so `while(*p)` is true for the entire length of your array, then it goes out of bounds, which is undefined behavior.

Your options are:

1. Pass the size along with the array, and use `int i = 0; while (i < LENGTH){}` or more idiomatically `for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)`
2. Use a designated sentinel value to indicate the end of the array and use `while (*p != SENTINEL)`

Former option is the least hassle and doesn't require you to designate an arbitrary `int` as a magic number.

Comment: A `for` loop is more idiomatic for option 1.